# Is Factor reliable to find factorization?

Tags: polynomials, factorization

I have two polynomials given by:

```
pol1[m_]=-1841504878942953083744409324868187492994498167115966796875 +580928493770985107820326304616514809348845549291934394531250 m -75024502885706095121603114224530193128338549528835833460937500 m^2 +5298925657163453777955255232567622332487122280459454380645625000 m^3- 227798365109668201365365179085359713340345609333042534931445750000 m^4 + 6234643254347521026564392321121203254954895883725417799236105700000 m^5 -109931649216658523777148132034696040607135448091444662328102077240000 m^6 +1231078593841754871953530891323886882150825573827191207597910477904000 m^7 -8346690238810542695206381988003526167288154316253859581516221092819200 m^8 + 30361253286990267418750317340168323322357764935142152595016669455070720 m^9 -39216649815260853136388340128801670825683951373094135212510242806043648 m^10 -31200431178403164530283275139303069690890304131559778448027666206853120 m^11 -8219539462328877944794781176249479500300711570681926587860899836416000 m^12 - 1039886007634837239367140032604908347357863410399660015064806006005760 m^13 - 64775153967170825528688821497476316434508832977561783722518350807040 m^14 - 1601840981499800816473320846390578910974221468020505318875962441728 m^15;
```

and

```
pol2[n_]=-623131210119254319579340517520904541015625 -103073215809586842806311324238777160644531250000 n -5082539520065755531379068046808242797851562500000000 n^2 -69640546955654002405478386803833770751953125000000000000 n^3 +514010725273019292655872388921796286949218750000000000000000 n^4 +3468277793540502153144535767873711384125936700000000000000000000 n^5 - 32063473617674476689282475044826138831298084932723200000000000000000 n^6 + 82066923745429352350072890484827347893180065670261137408000000000000000 n^7 -89582869100748382783027823531551494377825489661793879565795328000000000000 n^8 +44345746669088315370881052440694611814402939222300825771895035002880000000000 n^9 -9167934205260936843174009374977136703014603122209490501821274650700677120000000 n^10 +448733774740221380068584217234641234848723966315423691985007171402365874995200000 n^11 +14088864426876823657094384891357446211331244875462673884479845968274373298094080000 n^12 + 115495643678639078009546442411048074550486137241422263776190261914146252810040115200 n^13 +347019796200710566141847612782344686029571076662005362793768187422495674076569272320 n^14 +282756961676188130021118727351278339021334858342543008344186700690079840295381368832 n^15;
```

If I try `pol1[m]//Factor` or `pol2[n]//Factor` I get the same expressions back without any factorization taking place. Does this guarantee that the two polynomials are irreducible, or could it happen that the large coefficients make the `Factor` routine break down? Should I look further into trying to factor them?

Comment: I can't answer the question, but they're both irreducible, since both descend to the polynomial $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]$, which is irreducible.

Comment: Could you tell me more on how does one check the property you are mentioning?

Comment: A polynomial is irreducible if (but not only if) it is irreducible modulo some prime. You can do this in Mathematica with `Factor[pol2[n], Modulus -> 2]`, for instance.

Comment: I did not know this. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: The proof is easy: suppose $f \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$, and $f = f_1 f_2$ is reducible. Then mod $p$, we have $\bar{f} = \bar{f_1} \bar{f_2}$ where $\bar{f}$ represents the image of $f$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]$. That is $f$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Therefore, irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ implies irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: But what if both $\bar{f}_1$ and $\bar{f}_2$ reduce to $1$ mod $2$? Then we would find `Factor[pol2[n], Modulus -> 2]`$=1$ also, even though the original `pol2[n]` could actually factorize. Is there some mistake in this logic?

Comment: you are quite right. My bad - my reasoning is sound only if $f$ is monic.

Answer (score 4):

Amazingly, it turns out that there is a built in Mathematica routine to check whether a polynomial is irreducible or not:

```
IrreduciblePolynomialQ[]
```

Applied to the above two polynomials it confirms that both are in fact irreducible.

Comment: For univariate polynomials `IrreducibleQ will simply use `Factor`. For multivariate there are shortcuts available.